# Why can I not define a variable in this area of a Code Igniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried defining the array `$data` in my Code Igniter controller as follows.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

        /**
         * welcome controller
         */
        $data = array();

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
        }
    }

?>
```

However, this error surfaces.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in 
/home/users/davidfaux/testApp/application/controllers/welcome.php on line 8
```

Moving `$data` into the `index()` function fixes the error. Why?

Comment: Because that's how [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) and [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) works in PHP.

Comment: you should use private or public or static or protected before $data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

        /**
         * welcome controller
         */
        **private** $data = array();

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message', $this->data);
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: ignore the double asterisk :) I was trying to bold it - but do include that word there and try again.

Comment: Thanks, that does it! I've always thought PHP was very loosely typed. I guess it does have some strict rules to follow :)

Comment: This isn't so much a type issue as scope issue. It's loose on type, but does complain if you don't tell it what scope to put the variable within. In php4, you could have just use 'var' instead of one of those scope variables, but better to use them now and going forwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that by using var keyword

```
    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

        /**
         * welcome controller
        */
        var $data = array();

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message', $this->data);
        }
    }

?>
```